# Esri Query Task service does not display

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo, references

I am trying to make my way through some ArcGIS server Javascript API tutorials. My current issue is that when I try to display an Esri.Map, all I see is the "powered by esri" logo in the bottom right. My init is below as is my mapDiv.

```
function init () {

    map = new esri.Map("mapDiv",{
      basemap: "hybrid",
      center: [-80.94, 33.646],
      zoom: 8
    });

    //Create your query
    var queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Petroleum/KSFields/MapServer/0");
    //set the onComplete event handler, in this case, when the query is complete, call initLineID,
    //production code would handle handle the error callback as well
    dojo.connect(queryTask, "onComplete", initLineID);

    //build and execute your query
    var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
    query.outFields = ["field_name"];
    query.text = "all";
    query.returnGeometry = true;
    queryTask.execute(query);

}


<div id="mapDiv" style="width:900px; height:600px; border:1px solid #000;"></div>
```

Any reason why this would not be working?

Answer (score 3):

You are not adding a layer to the map which is why you only see the logo and a white map.

Try for example adding the world street map:

```
    var map = new esri.Map("mapDiv");
    var dynamicMapServiceLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");
    map.addLayer(dynamicMapServiceLayer);
```

Here is a simple map js fiddle that you can play with

http://jsfiddle.net/dave_wilton/mSQHp/

Comment: Thank you! How can I maintain the original code I had to start at a predefined lat/lon location and zoom level? I tried leaving that in the call to new esri.Map but it seems to be ignored.

Comment: After looking at this a little more, looks like I should have been more specific in the question. How can I accomplish this by using a basemap rather than a full layer? Here's an esri demo that accomplishes more or less what I'm after: http://www.esri.com/getting-started/developers/get-started/javascript

Comment: Appologies, you need to be clear on which version of the API you are trying to use too. Version 3.3 was just released this week and I haven't looked at it. Seems there are some changes to the map object. Fiddle updated to use version 3.3 and set the extent. http://jsfiddle.net/dave_wilton/mSQHp/

Comment: So in answer to your original question why does the basemap not show, perhaps it is that you are not using the latest version of the API?